# this code gives head->next = NULL although it should not

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// linked-list implementation of stack

typedef struct stack node;

struct stack{

    int value;
    node* next;    

};

void push(node*,int);
void pop(node*);



int main(){

node* head=malloc(sizeof(node));
head->next = NULL;
push(head,5);
if (head->next == NULL){
printf("head->next is NULL.");
}
pop(head);

}


void push(node* head,int value){

    head->value = value;
    node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;

}
```

The above code prints head->next = NULL although it should not because when push is called then temp->next = head and then head = temp so now the head->next should be equal to the previous head's location.

Comment: You never update `head->next`. `head = temp;` is modifying the local copy.

Comment: The logic in your last paragraph is wrong — `temp->next = head` then `head = temp` so `head->next == head`.

Comment: You do understand the concept of passing by value?

Comment: Search for and read about *emulating pass by reference in c*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, if I say head = temp now both are pointers so head now has the location of the newly created node right?

Comment: ***But*** the variable `head` inside the `push` function is a ***local*** variable. Once the function returns the variable will go out of scope and all changes to it will be lost.

Comment: oh yeah thanks that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in see that in your push() function you want to change the head of the list but actually you are passing it by-value so it will not be affected.

**node *head** means that you have a pointer to a NODE and  that you can actually modify only the properties of that NODE , not the head pointer itself.

you should use **node **head** which is a pointer to a pointer so it means that with it you can actually modify the head pointer.

[image]
[image]

That was a very short explanation... please try to read more about Pass-By-Value in C and Pass-By-Reference .

After this modification you must also pass the address of the head pointer as a parameter (&head) and make changes to it as *head ( in your function)

Here is the code:

void push(node**,int);
void pop(node*);

```
int main(){

node* head=malloc(sizeof(node));
head->next = NULL;
push(&head,5);
if (head->next == NULL){
printf("head->next is NULL.");
}
//pop(head);

}


void push(node** head,int value){

    (*head)->value = value;
    node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->next = *head;
    (*head) = temp;

}
```